# TypeORM "save" throws duplicate key error instead of ignoring identicalfiel fields

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I have an app using TypeORM with postgres. From what I have read in the docs, the repository .save() function saves OR updates a row in the database. So my entity has some unique fields that lead to typeorm throwing an exception due to duplicate key entries. Why is this happening, when it says thats save() updates rows if it finds them existing already or creates them if not?

I use save and pass an array of entities in it like this

```js
    await getRepository(Listing).save(orders);
```

```js
@Entity()
export class Listing {
    @PrimaryColumn("bigint")
    id: number

    @Column("jsonb")
    asset: {}

    @Column()
    expiration_time: number;

    @Column()
    listing_time: number;

    @Column({ unique: true })
    order_hash: string

    @Column()
    current_price: string

    @Column("jsonb")
    payment_token_contract: AssetContract

    @Column()
    cancelled: Boolean

    @Column()
    finalized: Boolean
}
```